# Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getData'

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am newbie of CoffeeScript and I want to get JSON from Flickr site.

```
class Photo
  json = null

  getData = (successCallback) ->
    $.getJSON(
      'http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?'
        format : 'json'
        method : 'flickr.photos.search'
        api_key : '7965a8bc5a2a88908e8321f3f56c80ea'
        user_id : '29242822@N00'
        per_page : '100'
      (data) =>
        @json = data.photos.photo;
        typeof successCallback == 'function' && successCallback())

photo = new Photo();
photo.getData successCallback = ->
  console.log('Data loaded', photo.json)
```

(same code is here: http://jsbin.com/eqoduv/3/edit )

But **"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getData'"** is returned.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems like you are not using the class syntax correctly: http://coffeescript.org/#classes.

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsbin.com/iruruk/1/edit

Comment: You can also have a look at the generated JavaScript, and you will see why you get the error: http://jsbin.com/eqoduv/4/edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This defines `getData` as a function (not even a method) that is private to the `Photo` class and not even visible to `Photo` instances:

```
class Photo
  getData = (successCallback) -> ...
```

Similarly, your `json` is a private class variable that will be shared by all instances of `Photo`. That means that the `json` in `json = null` is not the same `json` as `@json` in your callback.

You want `getData` to be a `Photo` method. You don't need to define `@json` at the `Photo` level at all, you can leave that up to your `$.getJSON` callback. And you can cleanup your "run `successCallback` if it is a function" test using the "is this a function" version of the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators):

```
class Photo
  getData: (successCallback) ->
    $.getJSON(
      #...
      (data) =>
        @json = data.photos.photo
        successCallback?()
    )
```

Note the `?` in `successCallback?()`, the checks that `successCallback` is a function before trying to call it.